# Dynamic Data Grid is required

Tags: dynamic, datagrid

i would like to ask about a data grid that changes dynamically based on the user selection.
so based on user selections inside the datagrid, the interface of this datagrid is changed and fetching some new data from DB.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for? You can easily set up text boxes that use combo boxes that will let you you display data in the datagrid, depending on the parameters that set from the combo box. e.g. Display all employees that have 'B' in their surname.

That would be out-with the datagrid however.

Is that the sort of thing that you want?